# Rails (gem bcrypt), has_secure_password, как сравнить значение со значением в БД?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Делаю на сайте возможность смены пароля пользователю.
Дело в том, что пароль хешируется в модели джемом bcrypt методом, встроенным в модель has_secure_password. А при изменении пароля пароль должен быть изменен только в том случае, если старый пароль (который установлен в данный момент) совпал с введенным. А, как мы знаем, в БД хранится хеш пароля, поэтому провести простое сравнение типа

```
if(@user.password_digest == params(:password))
```

Нам не удастся.
Собственно, отсюда вопрос: как сравнить новое значение пароля с хешированным паролем в БД, используя has_secure_password в модели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**зевает** [Документацию к `has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) смотрите:

```
# Schema: User(name:string, password_digest:string)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end

user = User.new(name: 'david', password: '', password_confirmation: 'nomatch')
user.save # => false, пароль обязателен
user.password = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe'
user.save # => false, подтверждение пароля отличается
user.password_confirmation = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe'
user.save                                                       # => true
user.authenticate('notright') # <- во-от так                    # => false
user.authenticate('mUc3m00RsqyRe')                              # => user
User.find_by(name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'notright')      # => false
User.find_by(name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'mUc3m00RsqyRe') # => user
```

Естественно, сравнение хэша с паролем не работает, это ж разные значения. Поэтому это должно быть сравнение вида `хэш_пароля == хэш(пароль)`. Но только в простейшем случае.

Comment: Именно о методе try я и не знал, спасибо *зевает* :)

Comment: @МатвейМамонов эм, мимо. Парой строчек выше :) Это для случаев, когда вместо пользователя может попасться `nil`. Это довольно *грязный* способ это обойти, но в совсем простых случаях это годится.

Comment: то есть пользоваться методом 'authenticate'? Я просто искал ему альтернативу типа 'authenticate?', который бы возвращал true, если пароли совпадают (хеш из БД и переданный)

Comment: @МатвейМамонов а он что делает, по-вашему? :)

Comment: Хотя да, действительно * *facepalm* *